# unicode capable bittorrent search engine

Tags: bittorrent, search-engines

Does anyone know of a way to search for bittorrents who's titles are in non english characters. In my case, I am looking for Korean language torrents, namely Korean TV Dramas.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.isohunt.com should work just fine.